# Java Binary Search tree method needs to return value instead of print

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a method that i need to return the BST values instead of printing them so i can send the results to a jtextarea instead of printing it. 
Here is the method:

```
public void printInOrder(BSTNode node) {
    if (node != null) {
        nodecount++;
        printInOrder(node.left);
        System.out.println(node.word + " - " + node.data);
        if (node.data == 1)
            uc++;
        printInOrder(node.right);
    }
}
```

And here is the code where im trying to call the method so that i can send it to the JTextArea.... Results is the name of the jtextarea

```
class Alphabetical implements ActionListener  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        File f = new File(dir.getText() + "\\" + filename.getText());
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            BSTFunctions bs = new BSTFunctions();
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                bs.insert(bs.ROOT, sc.next().toLowerCase().trim(), 1);
            }
            bs.printInOrder(bs.ROOT);
            results.append(bs.printInOrder(bs.ROOT));
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is preventing you from returning the value you are printing?

Comment: Add another argument List<String> to printInOrder method and use list.add() instead of System.out.print. Initially, you have to pass and empty list.

Comment: Just use a recursion with 'memory'. Add an empty list as parameter and collect the values there instead of printing them. Or alternatively implement BST non-recursive.

Comment: To make your code [mre] please hard-code test data, instead of using a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to do this is by means of some sort of callback that you pass to your method.
Try this:

```
public interface BSTListener
{
  public void onNode(BSTNode node);
}

public void callbackInOrder(BSTNode     node,
                            BSTListener listener)
{
  if (node != null)
  {
    callbackInOrder(node.left, listener);
    listener.onNode(node);
    callbackInOrder(node.right, listener);
  }
}
```

Then, you implement this listener that adds the nodes to your JTextArea:

```
BSTListener listener;
listener = new BSTListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onNode(BSTNode node)
  {
    results.append(node.word + " - " + node.data);
  }
};
bs.callbackInOrder(bs.ROOT, listener);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a `Consumer<BSTNode>`?

Comment: @daniu Because `Consumer` was introduced in Java 1.8 and some people (like yours truly) still use an old version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the callback solution, you might try to create a method that returns a list with the elements:

```
public List<String> listInOrder(BSTNode node)
{
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  if (node != null)
  {
    result.addAll(listInOrder(node.left));
    result.add(node.word + " - " + node.data);
    result.addAll(listInOrder(node.right));
  }
  return result;
}
```

This of course has the disadvantage that all elements are stored in memory for the second time.

Comment: This suggestion is working wonderfully, however, its listing it horizontally. I tried adding a "\n" to the results.add int he method, but it then prints nothing